# Is a VPN still effective after a hacker has known my IP address?

Tags: vpn, ip

A hacker has found my IP address. So, I've started to use SoftEther VPN through the instruction of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yo32MlgKt9g) to hide my IP. I would like to ask if my late action to hide my computer IP still works?

Comment: what do you mean "a hacker *found* my IP"?

Comment: I mean a person that is knowledgeable at IT has found my IP.

Comment: And what do you think that means? Why does this concern you?

Comment: According to this article ''Seven Scary Things Hackers Can Do to Your Computer'' [ http://whatismyipaddress.com/hacking-targets ], the person that has got my IP can steel my data and take control of my computer. I'm reading further to see what that person can do.

Comment: That article doesn't say that someone knowing your IP address is a bad thing. There aren't that many of them, after all (it is possible to scan every single publicly accessible one in less than an hour). You just need to make sure there isn't anything making you exposed to hackers on your IP address, usually by filtering any incoming data you aren't expecting.

Comment: It sounds like a big thing. How could I do to filter my incoming data ? Is there any software to do so ?

Comment: I've just read this article [https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/advice-from-real-hacker-know-if-youve-been-hacked-0157336/]. Is the suggested software named 'WireShark' a tool to filter the incoming data ?

Comment: Wireshark is a tool for professionals to analyze network data. Filtering incoming data is done by [firewalls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_firewalls#Firewall_software).

Answer (score 5):

Your IP address is something relatively easy to retrieve by different means. It's not a security problem if someone found yours. Your IP is just the address of your computer (or more likely your router).

Let's say that your computer is your house. The IP of your computer corresponds to the address of your house. You have to give the address of your house to access multiple services, there's nothing wrong with it. If you take care to lock your doors and close your windows, a burglar will have a hard time to get inside. It's the same with your computer, you have to keep it locked by frequently updating its software. In your house, you do not open your door to an unknown person, even more if this person wants to make you an offer too good to be true. It's the same with your computer: don't read e-mails you do not expect (especially their attachments, they could be trapped) and use an ad-blocker.

Using a VPN will just give you a false sense of security. That will not significantly improve your resistance to a hacker determined to harm you. That will not protect you against random threats (such as viruses or phishing attacks). Using a VPN is like telling people you're named John Doe: you will appear suspect and this will not stop a burglar to pay a visit to your house.

Answer (score 2):

The VPN will work regardless of whether somebody knows your IP.

However if you are using a VPN, someone who knows your real IP could still hack you since a VPN does not protect you from hackers using your IP in malicious ways.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any way I could do to change my real IP ?

Comment: If you have a dynamic IP, it will change ~every month. If you have a static IP, then it will stay the same and you will need to talk to your ISP and get them to change it. If you aren't sure what your IP type is, it's most likely dynamic.

Comment: I've just checked whether my IP is static or dynamic through the instruction of this site [ http://www.techbout.com/check-ip-static-dynamic-4135/ ]. My IP is static.